# react-loadable with Webpack 4 and Babel 7

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

strange thing happened after upgrade to babel 7
during server side rendering instead of returning used chunks it returns all available chunks, maybe someone knows anything about this.
It works perfectly doing only client side rendering.

my babel config:

```
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
  ],
  env: {
    production: {
      only: ['app', 'ssr'],
      plugins: [
        'react-loadable/babel',
        'lodash',
        'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements',
      ],
    },
    test: {
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
        'dynamic-import-node',
      ],
    },
  },
```

UPDATE:
maybe it will help someone, the problem was with a way i wrote imports, I used `import('./index')`, but in this wait it will make all the chunks have same key `./index` in react-loadable.json
The solution was to use absolute path instead of relative.

Comment: Please share you webpack and babel configuration.

Comment: added babel config